# GridView not displaying on webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to use gridview to display data from my database but I can't seem to get the gridview to display on the page. I inserted a breakpoint and the gridview shows the correct number of rows in the data source, and the correct number of rows in the gridview after databind. I am still not getting any display on the webpage, when inspecting where it should be with chrome I see the header tag but nothing related to the gridview. What am I doing wrong?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string id = Request.QueryString["profileID"];
        GridView achievementTable = new GridView();
        AchievementDatabaseTableAdapters.UserGamesTableAdapter UserGamesAdapter = new AchievementDatabaseTableAdapters.UserGamesTableAdapter();
        AchievementDatabase.UserGamesDataTable userGames = UserGamesAdapter.GetUserGames();
        achievementTable.DataSource = userGames.Select("ProfileID =" + id).CopyToDataTable();
        achievementTable.DataBind();
    }
}
```

.aspx code

```
<%@ Page Title="Profile" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Profile.aspx.cs" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" Inherits="AchievementProject.Profile" %>

<asp:Content ID="ProfileContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: Title %></h2>
    <asp:Gridview ID="achievementTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="Failed"></asp:Gridview>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

achievementTable is local to the page load event.  Move it to at least a protected variable at the class level and it will be available to your views.

Comment: This fixed the issue and I now get my table displaying properly. Thank you.

Comment: @Jordan Feel free to mark my answer as the correct one if it worked out for you.